# Placing a for loop within map?

Tags: python

I have the following x and I want to grab the index where an item == 0, such as index 2 in the below:

```
[['UNITED STATES', 'OHIO, USA'],
 ['NEW YORK, USA', 'UNITED STATES'],
 ['LYON, FRANCE', 'FRANCE', '0']
 ['FRANCE']]
```

I know how to solve this with a forloop, but I'm wondering if I can use map to do the same thing.

This doesn't work:

```
map(lambda y: i==0 for i in y, x)
```

For loop solution:

```
zero = []
for i, val in enumerate(x):
    for y, yval in enumerate(val):
        if yval == '0':
            zero.append(i)
```

Comment: Please specify whether you are using Python 2 or Python 3. The answer may differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map()` probably isn't the right approach because you will end up with a list that is the same length as your original.  So in this case the best you could do with `map()` is have it return `[False, False, True, False]`.

`filter()` might be more appropriate, but if you are just looking for a one-line solution a list comprehension is probably the way to go:

```
x = [['UNITED STATES', 'OHIO, USA'],
     ['NEW YORK, USA', 'UNITED STATES'],
     ['LYON, FRANCE', 'FRANCE', '0'],
     ['FRANCE']]
zero = [i for i, row in enumerate(x) if '0' in row]
```

Here is how it would look with `filter()`:

```
zero = filter(lambda i: '0' in x[i], range(len(x)))
```

Note that on Python 3.x `filter()` returns a generator instead of a list, so if you want the result to be a list you would would want `zero = list(filter(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python filter method much cleaner:

```
my_list.index(filter(lambda x: '0' in x, my_list)[0])
```

`filter(lambda x: '0' in x, my_list)[0]` return the first item containing 0
`my_list.index(<item>)` returns the index of that item

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `map`, you should use `filter`.

```
filter(lambda i: '0' in data[i], range(len(data))
```

However, filter is not considered pythonic. Clearer would be a list comprehension

```
[i for i in range(len(data)) if '0' in data[i]]
```

You can also remove the index variable by using enumerate.

```
[i for i, row in enumerate(data) if '0' in row]
```

Comment: 'not pythonic', then a line later, iterating by index. `filter()` is generally less readable than a list comp, but iterating by index is *never* the right solution in Python - much more unpythonic.